# Storing a list of users who have clicked a link in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm building a Hacker-News or Reddit style social news site with MongoDB. Let's suppose I wanted to store how many people clicked on each link, in order to factor the number of clicks into a link's popularity score. How should I organize my data? I could:

A) Store the array of users who clicked on a link in each link object.

B) Store the array of links clicked in each user object

C) Do both

D) Do something else… (but what?)

The advantage of A) is that getting the number of clicks for each link is trivial. On the other hand, the advantage of B) is that you can easily show users a history of the links they clicked. And of course C) lets you do both, but at the cost of duplicating data.

So which solution should I choose for the best performance? Is there a "right" way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the max size of a document, I'd probably add a new database like a redis one, with all this information. You can gain performance by doing that.
I had this problem with an app I build. In fact after a lot of likes, the documents will start to load slower.

But if you need to only have mongodb, I'd probably add them to another collection. That will give you some redundancy but that part is totally a relational part and can be somehow tricky with noSQL documents oriented databases.

To keep the ease of counting them, you could of course keep the number of likes on the link document. But I won't try to keep all the users that clicked there.
And won't embed that to a user neither.

Hope this helps

Comment: max size of a document won't be a problem

Comment: Good approach. If you want to push it further, you might have a look at: http://github.com/danlucraft/presentations/raw/master/denormalizing.pdf - Songkick actually uses MongoDB only for denormalization and keep their data normalized in a SQL DB. That keeps purposes separated. BTW, you can do the same with MongoDB only. Just differentiate your normalized and denormalized (caching) collections.

Answer (score 1):

In general, NoSQL databases encourage you to store data redundantly.  (This is because, since they do not support relational joins, denormalizing the schema somewhat is necessary to facilitate retrieval of the data.)  And in this case, as you noted, if you only store the links in the user's record, or vice versa, it will not be easy or efficient to perform all the queries you need (you'd have to basically scan every document in the collection).

So, I think the best approach is `C`, store the data both ways, for ease of retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each click on a document with the user and the link, then run queries to get both the number of clicks per link and a history of links they clicked.

(About performance, I don't know what it's worth, maybe put indexes on user and link)

Answer (score 0):

store the data in both collections... but just with the necessary properties.

In your app if you are going to need to reach that data in some where... it is best to get it in one map...

so if i were you i would not hesitate to duplicate the data...

on the other hand how many links or users we are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question

Just store the links in the user object, then use a number in link object to count the click number.

Then set a index on your links array in user object.

So you can

- Get all the click links in your user object.
- Use the link object to get the click count.
- Uuse the link index in user object to quickly find who click the link

Index array example: [How does MongoDB index arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059126/how-does-mongodb-index-arrays)